# CSS, page resolution independent webpage

Tags: css, position

I want to achieve result as drawn on the image (red square is  region, always fixed size, black square is the screen). I have no idea how to do this, unless here is a magical way of getting current size of screen and using conditional statements in CSS. Thanks!!

Here is the img: http://glothriel.org/uploads/layout.png

Comment: Just apply a fixed `width` to the red square and you are done with what you want as per the png screenshot. Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a fixed width div and `margin: 0 auto;`

```
div {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LqrWq/)

Comment: One other thing:
position: relative